# Не создается анонимный обработчик события C#

Tags: c#, winforms, события

К событию нажатия кнопки `Button.Click` не получается создать анонимный обработчик события.

`Ошибка CS1525: Unexpected symbol '{'.`

Код (Btn - кнопка):

```
Btn.Click += EventHandler(sender, e)
{  // Тут ошибка
   // Код
};
```

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас просто ошибка в синтаксисе.

Вот так это делается:

```cs
Btn.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
    // Код
};
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает. На [Metanite](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.14.php) почему-то => не указано.